# Modifying apacite reference style

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am trying to simulate my graduate school's references style using `apacite` package with `bibtex`. They claim their guidelines are close to APA but it is indeed an hybrid that no-one really accomplishes fully. Even though there seems to be no differences in entries with a single author between mine: [image: mine]

and the graduate school's
[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmXWe.png);

there is a quite difference when the resources have two [image]

or more authors [image] .

Here are the two author

[image]

and multiple author

[image]  in the reference style of the school. (The word *ve* means 'and' in Turkish.) Is there anyway to accomplish this entry style by modifying `apacite` 's attributes about two and multiple authored papers?

Comment: My Turkish is a little rusty: "ve" is "and"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry I've forgotten to explain it.

Comment: Is the issue the semicolon between multiple authors and the 've' instead of '&'? (Your school also puts a space between the volume and issue that isn't present in the APA version.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes as what you've said Alan. Also there is one additional issue; I found that instead of ampersand you can put any word you want, for example 'and' by `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}` but then the comma (,) before ampersand (&) remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of your school's specification can be obtained with the means of `apacite`, except the semicolon between multiple authors, which is hard-coded in `apacite.bst`.

The relevant changes are the redefinitions of `\BBAA`, `\BCBT`, and `\BCBL`, see the code. The space bewteen volume and issue is obtained by adding a `~` to `\APACjournalVolNumPages` when there is an issue number in the reference.

To get the semicolon, make a copy of `apacite.bst`, and change line 2320 in your copy from

```
FUNCTION {comma.between.names} { ", " }
```

to

```
FUNCTION {comma.between.names} { "; " }
```

Then we obtain

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}%% the 'and' between authors in a parenthetical citation and in the reference list
  \renewcommand{\BCBT}{}%% comma between authors in the reference section when there are two authors
  \renewcommand{\BCBL}{}%% comma before the last author when there are three or more authors in a citation and in the reference section
%% make a space between volume and issue:
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip~({#3})%      issue number; added the '~'
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}
}
\begin{document}
\cite{Ca04}% one author
\cite{StGu92}% two authors
\cite{GhJaEn02}% three authors

\bibliographystyle{oakenshieldapacite}%% based on apacite.bst
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: I was just about to post this answer too. Hopefully the school doesn't require a comma between multiple authors in citations as well as the semi-colon in the bibliography.

Comment: @AlanMunn Let's see whether the OP accepts it as is :-)

Comment: @mafp It worked flawlessly. Thank you very much. I have two more question: 1) Is it a more structured way to write a `turkish.apc` file for these kind of problems? 2) How can i change the "et al." abbreviation in multiply authored papers' citations to its Turkish counterpart "vd."

Comment: @oakenshield1 1) Yes, most definitely.You could even submit it to the authors of apacite. 2) The commands to change are `\BOthers` and `\BOthersPeriod`. Their default setting is `et al.\hbox{}`.